# Problema al crear NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigationview

En una actividad, intento crear un menú lateral. 
Para esto estoy utilizando el objeto NavigationView siguiendo este tutorial:

[Interfaz de Usuario en Android: Navigation Drawer (NavigationView)](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/interfaz-de-usuario-en-android-navigation-drawer-navigationview/)

El problema que tengo es que no me reconoce este objeto, el mensaje que me muestra en el Preview es el siguiente:

> **The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)**

He probado a añadir otras librerías pero me sigue dando error.

Mi fichero gradle es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.pablo.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 20       
    versionName "1.18"   
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.8'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

A raíz del comentario de @A.Cedano, he probado a poner el el fichero gradle la siguiente línea:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
```

pero me sigue dando error, el siguiente:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:21.0.3

Me da la opción de Install Repository and sync project pero al pulsarlo para instalar este repositorio no hace nada, no instala nada.

Comment: Te falta la librería de diseño en el `gradle`. Agrega esta dependencia: **`compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'`** Esa es la librería que usa el NavigationView (`<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView .../>`)

Comment: lo prueba y te digo, anteriormente he probado con otras de mayor versión y nada, espero que esta vaya bien

Comment: Ten cuidado con las versiones, deben estar todas iguales. Si tú pones aquí una de mayor versión no funcionará, porque tus otras librerías tienen la v. `21.0.3`. Es decir, todas las librerías de `support` que tienes deben ser de la misma versión. Si quieres poner una de mayor versión, lo cual no está mal, debes ponerlas todas en la misma versión.

Comment: Ese es el problema que me ha estado dando hasta ahora, he puesto librerías de mayor versión y aunque he subido el resto, me ha dado problemas. Ahora voy a probar la que me has puesto

Comment: Me sigue dando error, voy a editar mi respuesta para poner el error que me muestra

Comment: ¿Estamos de acuerdo en que pusiste eso en el `gradle` de la carpeta `app`, ¿cierto?  Por favor edita de nuevo para ver cómo quedó el `gradle`. Luego de actualizar el gradle **`Sync` es obligatorio**. Cuando termine de sincronizar entonces pruebas de nuevo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69368/discussion-between-pablo-simon-diestefano-and-a-cedano).